# How to access the inner element from an angularjs directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd like to compute the element scroller width, as the number of children x the width of first child.
To do that, I have designed a directive hscroller.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="scrollerContainer">
    <div id="photos" class="scroller" hscroller="hi!">
        <div ng-repeat="photo in stage.photos" 
            class="imageViewerBackground" 
            style="background-image: url(rsc/stage/{{stage.id}}/{{photo.file}}.thumb.jpg)"
            ng-click="openPopoverImageViewer('#photos', $index)"
            >
            <div>{{photo.description}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The directive is as follows:

```
app.directive('hscroller', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var pid=$(element).attr("id");
                var children = $(element).children();
                var id=$(children).attr("id");
                var firstChild = $(children[0]);
                var width = firstChild.width()*(children.length);
                console.log("openPopover hscroller: compute scroller (id="+id
                    +") width "+children.length+" children of "
                    +firstChild.width()+"px width, total="+width
                    + " (parentid="+pid+")"
                );

                $(element).css({"width":width+"px"});
        }
    };
});
```

While running, it sounds the directive has no children in there (a race condition with the ng-reapeat.?), the log is as follows:

```
[Log] openPopover hscroller: compute scroller (id=undefined) width 0 children of nullpx width, total=0 (parentid=photos)
```

I'm stuck with this, any idea?

Note: btw, all this is to adjust the width of the scroller element so that I could have a nice horizontal scroller on ipad device (Is there a fix in CSS?).

```
.hScrollable {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.scrollerContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: @popoverScrollHeight;
    .hScrollable;
}
.scroller {
    overflow: hidden;    // this is really important to avoid vertical scrolling on devices
    height: @popoverScrollHeight;
}
```

Comment: it really depends on the way the jquery plugin is written and you propably what to write your link code in a $timeout callback,trust me.Finally dont rewrap element in a jquery object when it's already a jquery object,makes no sense.

Comment: Could you setup a plunkr or something with an example? My gut is telling me that this is definitely something that should be accomplished with css.

Comment: I totally agree @theJoeBiz. Here is a CSS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/56gFf/5/

Comment: @mpm Thanks you very much. $timeout (which I didn't know yet) solved my race condition. I also removed the rewraps I had put in the last attempt to solve my issue. Please, write your comment as an answer so that I accept it!

Comment: @theJoeBiz I am really eager to solve the problem by using CSS only (that still makes me uneasy not to find the CSS solution). I hence produced a specific question and its fiddle right there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674913/how-to-properly-scroll-on-safari-mobile-ipad

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca ,très bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd propably want to write your code in the link function inside a $timeout callback.

No need to wrap element with jQuery since it's already a jquery object.

```
app.directive('hscroller', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            $timeout(function(){
                var pid=element.attr("id");
                var children = element.children();
                (...)
            });

        }
    };
});
```