# How to properly scroll on Safari mobile (iPad)?

Tags: html, ios, css

I need to handle both horizontal and vertical scrolling in a simple way, that works on Safari mobile in general and iPad in peculiar.

I have a very simple HTML/CSS framework which I wanted to keep very simple described as follows.

Find the [related fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/56gFf/5/).

**Horizontal scroller**

Unfortunately, this requires I compute the width of the scroller, depending on the content. Is there an automatic way?

The HTML is as follows:

```
       <div class="scrollerContainer hScrollable">
            <div class="scroller">
                <div id="photo1"></div>
                <div id="photo2"></div>
                <div id="photo3"></div>
                <div id="photo4"></div>
                <div id="photo5"></div>
                <div id="photo6"></div>
                <div id="photo7"></div>
                <div id="photo8"></div>
                <div id="photo9"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And the related CSS as follows:

```
.hScrollable {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

scrollerContainer {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
.scroller {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;    /* Really important to avoid vertical scrolling on devices */
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.scroller>div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Vertical scroller**

I'd like the content to fill the parent container, and is exceeding the vertical size, scroll vertically.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="container" style="height:400px">

        <div style="height:100px">
           Fixed content, I dont want to vscroll
        </div>
        <div class="tabContent">
           Potentially long content that should vscroll. 
           This div should fill to the end of the container. 
           I don't want to set its height to 300px, 
           but to find a way it does automatically. 
        </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a bit TOO much css happening in there. I updated your fiddle with the properties I moved/removed.

I removed `.hScrollable` and `.scrollerContainer` from the css and added the overflow properties right to `.scroller`.

So `.scroller` now looks like this:

```
.scroller {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56gFf/6/).

Comment: Thanks you @theJoeBiz you answered my question 1) (horizontal scroller). But I still have an issue with the vertical scrolling (second and third tab of the fiddle). I tried to translate your solution to it without success. Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/56gFf/14/

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca Your problem with the height is that you have the height on .scroller set to 50px. If you change that to min-height instead, .scroller will always be at least 50px, but it will actually end up being taller if the scroll bar appears (to accommodate the height of the scroll bar). I also changed overflow-x to auto on .hScrollable so that the scroll bar won't show unless the content is larger than 100%. http://jsfiddle.net/56gFf/15/

Comment: My point is about the vertical scroller (class vScrollable) associated to the tabContent (in the same filled). This is outstandingly demonstrated when your tap/click the third tab: the content of tabContent overflows vertically when asked to scroll within it as required by the vScrollable class. How it comes? @theJoeBiz

Comment: Hi @theJoeBiz, still looking into that in details. I've made my mind on it now and see the larger bottom "padding" below the scroller. I tried to remove it without success. Do you think it is what Safari keeps to hold the potential scroller tab? Any thoughts on that? http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/56gFf/19/